# Is it possible to give too little sadaqah?

Tags: sadaqah

Sometimes I worry that when I give in voluntary charity, I give too little.

In a sense, no matter how much I give, I could have given more. But I can feel bad if I could have easily given more, but didn't. Simultaneously, it's surely better to give something rather than nothing at all. I'm conflicted about this.

**Question**: Is it possible to give too little sadaqah?

Comment: Short answer: No. What counts is that it comes from the heart and with a pure intention!

Comment: Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said, "Guard yourselves against the Fire (of Hell) even if it be only with half a date-fruit (given in charity); and if you cannot afford even that, you should at least say a good word."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Hadith that is often recited during fund raisers:

> Abu Hurairah narrated that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said:
>
> “Take on only as much as you can do of good deeds, for the best of
>   deeds is that which is done consistently, even if it is little.”
>
> حَدَّثَنَا الْعَبَّاسُ بْنُ عُثْمَانَ الدِّمَشْقِيُّ، حَدَّثَنَا
>   الْوَلِيدُ بْنُ مُسْلِمٍ، حَدَّثَنَا ابْنُ لَهِيعَةَ، حَدَّثَنَا
>   عَبْدُ الرَّحْمَنِ الأَعْرَجُ، سَمِعْتُ أَبَا هُرَيْرَةَ، يَقُولُ
>   قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ ـ صلى الله عليه وسلم ـ ‏:‏ ‏ "‏ اكْلَفُوا مِنَ
>   الْعَمَلِ مَا تُطِيقُونَ فَإِنَّ خَيْرَ الْعَمَلِ أَدْوَمُهُ وَإِنْ
>   قَلَّ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ Grade   : Sahih (Darussalam)
>
> English reference  : Vol. 5, Book 37, Hadith 4240 Arabic reference     :
>   [Book 37, Hadith 4381](https://sunnah.com/urn/1343800)

If spending a little allows you to consistently do Sadaqah  for helping others it is more better than to spent irregularly on Sadaqah.

One of the local Imams explained to me this is so that we remember Allah more often which leads to us doing more good deeds and avoiding sins. Also a lot of more people tend to benefit from your Sadaqah this way.

Also as pointed out by Saif in a comment to your question, it is not the amount but the intention that matters most. Dont be stingy but also dont spend overtly that your family gets affected .

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course .

> حَدَّثَنِي أَبُو غَسَّانَ الْمِسْمَعِيُّ، حَدَّثَنَا عُثْمَانُ بْنُ
>   عُمَرَ، حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو عَامِرٍ، - يَعْنِي الْخَزَّازَ - عَنْ أَبِي
>   عِمْرَانَ الْجَوْنِيِّ، عَنْ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ الصَّامِتِ، عَنْ
>   أَبِي ذَرٍّ، قَالَ قَالَ لِيَ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ لاَ
>   تَحْقِرَنَّ مِنَ الْمَعْرُوفِ شَيْئًا وَلَوْ أَنْ تَلْقَى أَخَاكَ
>   بِوَجْهٍ طَلْقٍ ‏"‏ ‏.‏
>
> *Abu Dharr reported: Allah's Apostle (ﷺ) said to me: Don't consider anything insignificant out of good things even if it is that you meet
>   your brother with a cheerful countenance** ([2626 Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/45/187))